# Understanding complex conjugates...

Tags: calculus

Is it right?
 \begin{equation}\overline{(-1+i)} = (1-i)
\\ \sqrt[4]{-625} = \pm5i \end{equation}
And what does n in this equation means?
\begin{equation}z = -\sqrt2 -\sqrt2i \\n= 9\end{equation}
Is it some sort of misunderstanding or am I missing something?

Comment: Note that $\overline{(-1+i)}$ is actually $-1-i$, not $1-i$.

Comment: There's not enough information in your question to figure out what $n$ means.  Could you explain what you're working on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
\overline{-1+i} = -1-i
$$

The complex conjugate flips the sign of the imaginary part.

To find the nth root of a number, express in polar form first. The rest should be simple. You can easily check your answer by taking your result to the 4th power and seeing if it agrees.